# check uncheck checkbox using angularjs using attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I want to add checked and unchecked attribute to the checkbox which is in a table I tried to using it via jquery  in angularjs

```
$('#chksitecolumn_' + item.Id).attr('checked', true)
```

Here `item.Id` is the id which I am iterating and binding it on `ng-model`.

and also tried it using angularjs

```
var element = angular.element('#chksitecolumn_' + item.Id);
element.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

but it is not working

Here is my checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="test"  id="chksitecolumn_{{item.Id}}"
       ng-model="selected[item.Id]"/>
```

I am passing an ID as a key using `ng-model` I want to know that can we check uncheck checkbox except using `ng-model`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ng-model`?

Comment: I am using ng model to pass  the Id i know it can be done using ng-model but want to know can we check unckeck it except using ng-model

Comment: You should probably not mix AngularJS and jQuery, but if you must, use `prop('checked', true)`, not `attr('checked', true)` or `attr('checked', 'checked')`. See "Attributes vs. Properties" [in the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 1):

To check/uncheck you can use `ng-checked` directive ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)) :

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="test" id="chksitecolumn_{{item.Id}}"
       ng-checked="checked[item.Id]" />
```

Note that you should not use `ng-checked` with `ng-model` together:

> Note that this directive should not be used together with `ngModel`, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: And how can i bind it in angular

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 Use `ng-checked` for one-way binding. Use `ng-model` for two-way binding. Don't use the `ng-checked` and `ng-model` directives together on the same input element.

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 You can set the assigned variable as true/false from the controller